# how to hit a specific end point using json server

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have set up json-server using a react app and I had a quick question about end points

this is some of my data:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "football",
      "id": "SPO-001",
      "category": "sport",
      "price": "40",
      "coupons": ["daw124qdw", "a1212cxn"]
    },
    {
      "name": "cricket bat",
      "id": "SPO-002",
      "category": "sport",
      "price": "80"
    }
]
}
```

and it all works fine when i do something like this:

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:3004/products').then(({ data }) => {
    // do something with data
  })
```

and I know I can do: `http://localhost:3004/products/SPO-001` which returns me the id for that. but how can I just return the coupons entry for that specific id? is that a possible endpoint?

I tried `axios.get('http://localhost:3004/products/SPO-001/coupons')` but I just got an empty object. any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to list coupon's value?

Comment: yes essentially. I would like to hit it as an endpoint and have that just returned to me. rather than filtering on the client side. I want to mimic backend behaviour by hitting that direct endpoint

Comment: Can you something like this code:

`fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/6d0ps/").then(function(res) {
 return res.json()
}).then(function(data) {
 data.products.map(val =>{
     console.log(val.coupons)
 })
})`

Comment: Let me know if it helps you?

Comment: well yes I can do, but that's doing it on the client side. i was wondering if there was a way to directly query the server like a database. rather than pulling back all the data and then doing something with it client side. if that makes sense

Comment: can you provide your api endpoint code for this route?

Comment: @CharisTheo im using express now as it's more flexible for my needs

Comment: yes I meant the code for the route like this app.get(/products,function(){ //your logic })

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1st

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3004/products')
     .then(res => this.setState({product: res.data.productID.coupon})) // not sure how you want to use your response, this is just an example
```

2nd create your endpoint for each product, something like `http://localhost:3004/:productID/coupon` and then "hit" that endpoint with your axios get request, e.g. `axios.get('http://localhost:3004/23/coupon').then(res => res.data)`

I would have to say the 2nd option would be more robust.

Comment: the second option is exactly what i want. would this return me the coupons array?

Comment: depend how you structure your api end point. if each product has a property that it's called coupon and the value is an array then yes, it will return the array of coupons for that specific productID

Comment: yes sure, but you can see the structure above and when I do this: `http://localhost:3004/products/SPO-001/coupons` it just returns me an empty object :/

Comment: An empty object probably means that you haven't structured correctly your api endpoint in the backend...however this isn't always the case